# How can I build these custom Box-shadow css3 effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get these
[image]

These is the markup i'm using

```
<ol>
  <li><a>Campo</a>
    <ol>
      <li><a>Informacion Agricola</a></li>
      <li><a>Fabrica</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li><a>Gastos Reales Campo</a>
</ol>
```

The problem I'm having is that box-shadown doesn't have 3 side border effect, my initial idea was that the first menu had 3 side shadow, top, left and right, and then the submenu was going to have the 4 border shadown and be behind that menu and a little up so it got superposed but it's not working as I can't have a 3 side box shadown.

Is there any other optimal way to made these?

Comment: Show your idea in Photoshop or something like that at least.

Comment: Sorry, I added and image with the effect I was talking about but maybe  the firewall where I'm filtered

Comment: Added a new image, hope now you can see it

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create three separate shadows with no (or very little) blur, and offset them in the three directions.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5363378/212443) for a similar example.